# What is the correct way to submit a foreign key in a form and tie it to a reference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have models with references:

```
Vacation
  name:string
  slug:string:uniq
  start_at:datetime
  end_at:datetime

Transportation
   name:string

Destinations
  vacation:references
  transportation:references
  name:string
  full_address:string
  latitude:float
  longitude:float
  position:integer
```

I am wondering how can I add a reference in a form submission? I have a form working:

```
<%= form_for(@vacation) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :vacation %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :name %>
      <%= f.submit "Create" %>
```

when I submit, it now shows up on the home page. I want to pick a vacation from a select box (I'm close to handling that), like vacation with ID=2, and on form submission, tie this new destination to the selected vacation: ID=2. My working example looks like:

```
    def create
        @vacation = Vacation.new(vacation_params)
        if @vacation.save
            redirect_to '/'
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private 
      def vacation_params
          params.require(:vacation).permit(:name)
      end
```

Thank you

Comment: are there relationships between the models? `belongs_to` / `has_many` / `has_one`

Comment: Yes, I'm also on the task.  I have an attempt but it isn't saving:
        `<%= f.label :vacation %><br />
        <%= f.select :vacation_id, options_for_select(Vacation.all.map{|v|[v.name, v.id]}) %>`

Comment: We have a form that makes a new destination which contains the above code ^, but it makes a destination correctly except it doesn't add the Vacation as a FK. The vacation select box does show our vacations

Comment: With this layout, the table `destinations` must have a column `vacation_id` (please check it /add it if necessary ). You can create a new migration and add this column if necessary

Comment: `create_table "destinations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "vacation_id" .....`

Now I'm more baffled.

Comment: I allow it in the view: `params.require(:destination).permit(:vacation, :name, :full_address)`

Comment: Vacation id comes up in the POST, but does not get added in the SQL as follows:

Comment: `...
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "destination"=>{"vacation_id"=>"40", "name"=>"fake post", "full_address"=>"fake post", "latitude"=>"fake post", "longitude"=>"fake post"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
Unpermitted parameters: vacation_id, latitude, longitude
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "destinations" ("name", "full_address", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "fake post"], ["full_address", "fake post"], ...]`

Comment: you might want to permit these ones as well `vacation_id, latitude, longitude` as your log have them Unpermitted

Comment: The FK must be explicitly named "modelname_id", not "modelname" as in Django. Thank you Fabio

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is a [select_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag):

You could add this line inside your form (you are going in the right track), so you select an existing vacation:

```
<%= select_tag "vacation_id", options_from_collection_for_select(Vacation.all, "id", "name") %>
```

And the structure of your tables should be as we discussed below the question.

Happy to have helped.